# Ruby on Rails form building simplification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

thanks for taking the time to read this.

I'm trying to build a form that accepts multiple members. It starts off with 3 members and then there's a javascript button that adds a member, with a maximum of 100 members. The only way I can figure out how to do it is by hard coding all the form elements as below 1..100 (I only showed 1-4) and then hiding all the extras.  The javascript button then just displays the next element.  Is there a way I can generate the form element in the javascript?  Or is there a way to use a loop to create the 100 hard coded elements?

```
    <tr id="member_1">
      <td></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_1_name, :value=>@members[:member_1_name]) %></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_1_number, :value=>@members[:member_1_number]) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="heading">Member Names</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="member_2">
      <td></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_2_name, :value=>@members[:member_2_name]) %></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_2_number, :value=>@members[:member_2_number]) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="member_3">
      <td></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_3_name, :value=>@members[:member_3_name]) %></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_3_number, :value=>@members[:member_3_number]) %></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr id="member_4" style="display:none">
      <td></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_3_name, :value=>@members[:member_3_name]) %></td>
      <td class="field"><%= text_field(:members, :member_3_number, :value=>@members[:member_3_number]) %></td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks Again!  Let me know if something isn't clear and whatnot

Comment: Are these members activerecord objects? Do they have common parent?

Comment: No, they're not I do a bunch of processing in the controller on them and then add them to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of functionality is covered in episodes 196 & 197 of RailsCasts

[Nested Model Forms Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) | [Nested Model Forms Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

You should create only first member and put hidden div with template on a page. Javascript button should use this template and insert new field with it. See for example: http://embeddedjs.com/